# Compiling Mpeg-7 XM Software on Windows

Tags: imagemagick, compilation, imagick, mpeg

I need to compile Mpeg 7 XM Reference Software on windows for a school project.
I downloaded it from this link:
 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c035364_ISO_IEC_15938-6%28E%29_Reference_Software.zip

However, it is a quite old project and I am having issues compiling it on windows.
Under "XMWin/newsrc/XMWinExe/" folder, there is a visual c++ project. I gathered all the dependencies according to Compilation.txt (which is under the newsrc folder) and tried to compile, but it failed.

At last, all the errors disappeared except for this: it can not find "Imagick.lib"

The project needs ImageMagick 4.2.* c-api, so I downloaded it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick/files/old-sources/4.x/4.2

But there weren't an Imagick.lib file. I compiled "Magick++.dsw" but it wasn't created. How can I find or create it ? Or else, am I doing something wrong, maybe it should not complain about this .lib file ? Anyone who had experience with this Mpeg-7 Xm Software before ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it. Here is what I've done:

- I installed Image Magic 5.5.7 Q16 binaries
- A lib file (namely "CORE_RL_magick_.lib") was created under "Program Files\ImageMagick-5.5.7-Q16\lib" folder.
- I copied that file to "XMWin\ImageMagick\lib" folder and changed its name to "Imagick.lib"

It was really hard to find, but it worked. After these changes, It was successfully compiled. 
And here is the system: Windows XP SP3, Visual C++ 6.0 Standard Edition. Also, it may work on many other versions as well.